# Accepting parameters from user in a middle job of a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have jenkins pipeline with 3 jobs. The first one is run using SCM polling, the second one is triggered automatically and the third one is run manually. Is it possible for the third job to let the user type build parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Jenkow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkow+Plugin); it's a little heavyweight, but is the only way I know to include manual steps in Jenkins job pipelines.